# Twilio security features

Tags: security, twilio

Are there security measures to avoid Billing Overflow?
Are there features like a list to restrict numbers?

If they exist, where can I enable them?

I am currently using the Whatsapp service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will implement this logic server side programmatically, since you are calling the [Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api) to send a WhatsApp message on behalf of the end-user.

Comment: appreciate it a lot.
I have another question.
Where is the input and output information of whatsapp messages stored?
If it can be saved, what information is saved?